# Ideas for non-technical exercises to reinforce the concept of test-driven development?

Tags: tdd

I'm running a course to help students understand some important technology concepts, but the students do not know how to code (nor is this the point of the course).

For many concepts / practices in web development, I've come up with non-technical exercises that give them an understanding for how the tech equivalent works.  For example, to explain Pair Programming, I have students solve a logic puzzle by themselves first, and then solve a puzzle of similar difficulty in pairs. This highlights both the positives and negatives the pair programming experience.

I am struggling to come up with a similarly non-technical example or exercise that would help them understand the pros and cons of TDD.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend asking this on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest searching for TDD analogies such as this one:

[The Door analogy](http://reflectivecoder.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/tdd-door-analogy.html)

Perhaps this will give you some inspiration. Expand this out and explain the benefits as you work through the example?